# Subdomain 000Webhost

Tags: seo, google, domains, wordpress, subdomain

I'm currently learning to create a blog using wordpress.org. My site is hosted free on 000webhost. I have trouble creating a Subdomain for my website. This is what I have done so far. Somebody please guide me

**Main Domain work correctly with these settings**

**DNS Setting**

```
Point A(Address) "IP Address" to @
Point A(Address) "IP Address" to www
```

**Wordpress Setting**

```
WordPress Address (URL) = http://www.mydomain.com
Site Address (URL) = http://www.mydomain.com
```

**000Webhost Setting**

```
Parked Domains = http://mydomain.com
Created a database for maindomain
```

Copied Wordpress into /public_html/

---

**Subdomain doesnt work with these settings**

**DNS Setting**

```
Point A(Address) "IP Address" to subdomain
```

**Wordpress Setting**

```
WordPress Address (URL) = http://subdomain.mydomain.com
Site Address (URL) = http://subdomain.mydomain.com
```

**000Webhost Setting**

```
Added a Subdomain = http://subdomain.sample.site.net
Created a database for subdomain
```

Created a folder including copied wordpress in /public_html/subdomain

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the new subdomain returning a 404 (page not found) error or what?

Answer (score 1):

In 000webhost you are only allowed to make two MySQL databases. Make sure you have one for your sub domain. I am not sure whether you are allowed to create a sub domain like `http://subdomain.sample.site.net`

only two My SQl databases are allowed in their free account...
provide further details of your problem mate...

Answer (score 0):

If you're being allowed to host for free, chances are that you're not allowed subdomains by your hosting provider.

Please confirm this, as this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to any hosting panel like cPanel? If yes, you will have to create a sub-domain first and redirect it if that is required.

Please let us know if you have access to any hosting panel like cPanel.